# Why does using preprocessing mode give me this error?

Tags: error-handling

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file 'x64\Release\FileName.obj'   Project10   C:\Users\zadge\source\repos\Project10\Project10\LINK    1
```

i tried enabling preprocessor and i expected it to work but it gave me that error

Comment: This looks like a linking error (code LNK), so preprocessing would seem to be irrelevant

Comment: when i enable preprocessing this happens but without it its fine

Comment: What do you mean by "enable preprocssing"?  The preprocessor always runs when you run the compiler and does not run when you run the linker.  The only place it might be optional is when building .asm files